# ToyVPN Example uin android and shared secret

Tags: android, vpn

I have downloaded ToyVPN example and I want to test it

I have the following information :

Server IP, Server port, Username, Password

What application needs from me (Server IP, Server port, Shared Secret)

I don't know what is the meaning of shared secret, and how to be able to use my (username and password)

Please if anyone can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shared Secret is the "password" used to connect to the server.

As ToyVPN is just a proof-of-concept demo, it does not support multiple {username, password} pairs. So you don't need a username for that.

Comment: so do you mean that I will use my password in the shared secret field and It will connect to vpn network ??

Comment: Yes. And you need to setup the ToyVPN server with the same shared secret.

Comment: Actually I am new using VPN so I don't have enough information about it, all what I need to do is to be able to make my application use vpn connection using (Server IP, Server port, Username, Password), so if you have any example or open source code or tutorial that can help me I will be thankful

Comment: So are you just trying out ToyVPN, or what kind of VPN server you're trying to connect to? Either way, I suggest you to study the ToyVPN example code carefully (it's well documented), and also Android's Reference on [VpnService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html). There should be enough information to get you started.

Comment: I'm try to connect to server with PPTP protocol, and I can't find anything that specify the protocol in ToyVPNm I have user name and password, but I couldn't understand how to set the protocol and set usename and password??

Comment: Unfortunately ToyVPN does not use PPTP protocol (it uses its own). You'll have to come up with your own implementation of PPTP VPN client instead, if you do not want to use the VPN client already built-in in the OS.

Comment: Oh no, do you know if there are any open source libraries that implement PPTP protocol in android, this task is scheduled to be finished today, and I don't have any experience writing such protocols.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an expert on PPTP, so couldn't give any more help on this... May Google be the best luck of you...

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot for your help, I am really thankful, Do you have any information if I can download vpn profile file and import it to vpn connections and auto configure it, it may be a work around not to implement PPTP protocol myself

Comment: Hello @AmiraElsayedIsmail, did you found any open source code for PPTP. It means just suggest me how to lead the PPTP protocol in VPN.

Comment: hi . did anyone found any solution for PPTP ?